# SharedPreferences Integers wont save

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to save two integers in SharedPreferences but they won't get saved.
I have a RangeSlider with a min and max value. The slider values definetly get updated but when I save them and call sharedPreferences.getInt(...); the values are not saved. Shared Preferences has still the default value.
Does anybody see what my mistake is?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSettingsBinding binding;
    private SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        this.settingsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SettingsViewModel.class);
        this.settingsViewModel.setRepository(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getRepository());

        sharedPreferences =  requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        this.binding.sliderMinMaxSetting.addOnChangeListener(new RangeSlider.OnChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(@NonNull @NotNull RangeSlider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), Math.round(slider.getValues().get(0)));
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), Math.round(slider.getValues().get(1)));
                sharedPreferences.edit().commit();

                int min = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMinDefaultValue));
                Log.d("SettingsFragment", "minSharedPref : " + min + ", minSlider : " + Math.round(slider.getValues().get(0))); // Result: slider value is updated but not shared preferences

            }
        });       

        this.binding.buttonResetSettings.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMinDefaultValue));
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMaxDefaultValue));

            sharedPreferences.edit().commit();

            updateUiWithSharedPrefData();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Settings reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        updateUiWithSharedPrefData();

        return this.binding.getRoot();
    }


    private void updateUiWithSharedPrefData(){

        Log.d("SettingsFragment", "min / max : " + sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMinDefaultValue)) + " / " + sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMaxDefaultValue)));

        List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>();
        float min = (float) sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMinDefaultValue));
        float max = (float) sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMaxDefaultValue));

        floats.add(min);
        floats.add(max);

        binding.sliderMinMaxSetting.setValues(floats);

    }
}
```

Thanks for the answers.
This is the solution:

```
sharedPreferences.edit()
                        .putInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), Math.round(slider.getValues().get(0)))
                        .putInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), Math.round(slider.getValues().get(1)))
                        .commit();
```

Comment: Dont use putInt() and getInt(). They dont work. Just use putString() and getSting().

Comment: Ah .. i see now that you use `putInt(getString())`. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @blackapps
I thought that I need a string for the name so that this integer can be found or edited:
putInt( integerName, integerValue) and for getting the value: getInt(integerName, defaultValue). And the defaultValue is just the value of integerName if nothing has been saved under this name.
Because I want to make sure that I get the correct integer, I saved the name as a String in my strings.xml and the default value also as a fixed value in my integers.xml
I thought this was the correct way. So putInt and getInt don't work? Why?
I will try it with Strings.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment. I was completely wrong. And i never got it to work with Int. Thats all.

Comment: I think you get a new editor instance every time you call `edit()`. You should get just one editor, call `putInt` on it, then call apply() (or commit)

Comment: @TylerV I tried this:
`sharedPreferences.edit()
                        .putInt(minVipActionsString, Math.round(slider.getValues().get(0)))
                        .commit();`

and this after another:

               `sharedPreferences.edit()
                        .putInt(maxVipActionsString, Math.round(slider.getValues().get(1)))
                        .commit(); `

but this also worked so it's probably only the commit() that I did wrong

Comment: That works too - I added an answer showing an alternate way of doing it and some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should commit right after editing:

```
sharedPreferences.edit()
    .putInt(PREF_KEY, PREF_VALUE)
    .commit();
```

Also take into account the edits can be concatenated, so your code would look like this:

```
sharedPreferences.edit()
    .putInt(getString(R.string.settingMin), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMinDefaultValue))
    .putInt(getString(R.string.settingMax), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.settingMaxDefaultValue))
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a correct way of doing this, but you can also simply make sure you use the same Editor instance if you want multiple `putX` calls without chaining the calls into one line of code, like this:

```java
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
ed.putInt("somekey", 1);
ed.putInt("otherkey",2);
ed.apply(); // or ed.commit()
```

The reason the original code did not work is because each time you call `edit()` it returns a [brand new Editor instance](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#359). It was the equivalent of calling

```java
SharedPreferences.Editor ed1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
ed1.putInt("somekey", 1); // this change never gets committed because you never call commit on 'ed1'

SharedPreferences.Editor ed2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
ed2.putInt("otherkey", 2); // this change never gets committed because you never call commit on 'ed2'

SharedPreferences.Editor ed3 = sharedPreferences.edit();
ed3.commit() // this does nothing since ed3 had no changes
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your `SharedPreferences` initialization with this:

> SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem for me